# Xamarin - using async/await and a UserDialogs.Instance.Loading

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asynchronous

I have an app where I download a zip. Now I want it to show a loading dialog during this download until the await method is over. But it is not shown.

Obviously I want this to be shown until await is over.

This is my code so far

```
private async Task DownloadMediaById(int id, int versionnr)
{
    string path = PathToZip();

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        MyListView.IsVisible = false;

        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading", null, null,
        true, MaskType.Black))
        {
            await Api.DownloadMediaById(id, versionnr);
        }

        MyListView.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

And this is the method for downloading

```
    public static async Task DownloadMediaById(int id, int versionnr)
    {
        string FolderName = SyncContent.GetZipName(id, versionnr);
        try
        {
            using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading", null, null,
            true, MaskType.Black))
            {
                await DownloadingSingleZip(FolderName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

How can i get my loading dialog to work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
async Task MyMethod()
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading", MaskType.Black);
    await Api.DownloadMediaById(id, versionnr);
    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
}
```

```
public static async Task DownloadMediaById(int id, int versionnr)
    {
        string FolderName = SyncContent.GetZipName(id, versionnr);
        try
        {
            await DownloadingSingleZip(FolderName);          
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```